# XSD : how to restrict attribute inherited from base type

Tags: xsd

Consider the following XSD schema.

I have to types: `AddressType` and `USAddressType`.

- For `AddressType`, `Line1` can be any string.
- For `USAddressType` I want to restrict `Line1` attribute to follow some regular expression.

How can I do this? Thanks!

```xml
<xs:complexType name="AddressType">
    <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="Line1" type="xs:string"/>
    </xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>


<xs:complexType name="USAddressType">
    <xs:complexContent>
        <xs:extension base="AddressType">
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element name="State" type="xs:string"/>
                <xs:element name="Zipcode" type="xs:string"/>
            </xs:sequence>
        </xs:extension>
    </xs:complexContent>
</xs:complexType>
```

Answer (score 0):

```xml
<xs:element name="Line1">
    <xs:simpleType>
        <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
            <xs:pattern value="REGEX HERE"/>
        </xs:restriction>
    </xs:simpleType>
</xs:element>
```

Limitations of regular expressions used in XML Schemas can be found **[here](http://www.regular-expressions.info/xml.html)**